# Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. setState throws error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

```
export class ABC extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      abc: null
    };
  }

  renderOptions() {
      this.setState({
        abc: abcArray.length !== 0
      });
    return;
  }

  renderRadio() {
    return (
          <Field
            id="abc"
            name="abc"
            values={this.renderOptions()}
          />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
               {this.renderRadio()}

      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ABC);
```

I am trying to setState in renderOptions() which gives me the below error.

Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

can't get my head around what im doing wrong here.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in renderRadio() -> `values={this.renderOptions()}` you are calling the renderOptions function. that function calls the `this.setState({abc: abcArray.length !== 0});`. then react will try to rerender the component. this will create a loop. to avoid it, you should change values prop to this `values={this.renderOptions}`

I've refactor your code.

```
export class ABC extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      abc: null
    };
  }

  renderOptions() {
      this.setState({
        abc: abcArray.length !== 0
      });
    return;
  }

  renderRadio() {
    return (
          <Field
            id="abc"
            name="abc"
            values={this.renderOptions}
          />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
               {this.renderRadio()}

      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ABC);
```

Comment: this din't work for me, I just moved all the code that's inside the renderOptions into the renderRadio function to make it work (without having to use the state variable)

Answer (score 0):

Your `render` method is calling `setState`, which will trigger `render` to be called again.

You should not call `setState` inside of `renderOptions`.